# Amarok in kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kubuntu, amarok

I just have upgraded from kubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 and I found Amarok player has disappeared!

How could I install it again?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install it originally? did you use a PPA that is not enabled yet?

Comment: I had installed it using kubuntu repositories in 18.10. When I upgraded to 19.04, the upgrade program told me amarok was going to be deleted

Comment: Thanks @DKBose, I will try it too, but I really want my Amarok back! :(

Comment: ...so I tryed to compile it from sources, but it throws me a lot of errors. It requires QT4 to compile and I have version 5

Comment: Yes, I compiled that source code with errors

Comment: If you're good at coding stuff, and you still have access to Kubuntu 18.10, you could make an AppImage for Amarok (on the 18.10 system) which you could then use as standalone software on 19.04. See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/Creating-AppImages and https://discourse.appimage.org/t/how-to-create-an-appimage/155.

Comment: You may also install Clementine https://www.clementine-player.org, it is the official KDE successor to Amarok

Comment: It's not straightforward but possible to build on 20.04 now. More details later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create an AppImage from deb files with pkg2appimage.

amarok.yml

```
app: Amarok
ingredients:
  dist: disco
  packages:
    - amarok
  sources:
    - deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main universe
    - deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe
```

Then run `bash -ex ./pkg2appimage amarok.yml` (with https://github.com/AppImage/pkg2appimage/blob/master/pkg2appimage)

The result is an AppImage that runs on a system with Amarok installed but not if not installed (native).

My solution for now is to add the bionic tls sources again and install amarok from there. This is not a very clean solution but the simplest for now.

Add to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe
```

Then run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install amarok`.