# Why was Amarok removed from 19.04 repositories?

Tags: 19.04, amarok

Is there an official explanation somewhere? I understand that it's maybe not maintained enough but what is the exact reason? Did something stop working? What are the parameters by which a project is deemed not maintained?

`easystroke` for example is [unmaintained for 6 years](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/commits/master) and [crashes Xorg randomly on 18.04](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/commits/master) but it is [still available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=easystroke) and I'm very glad it is.

And `amarok` has [active contributions](https://cgit.kde.org/amarok.git/log/) and I'm not aware of any issue [running it on `disco`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1135203/20275).

Comment: if you download its source will it compile on 19.04?

Comment: @ScottStensland It's a different question and I haven't tried it https://askubuntu.com/q/1135203/20275

Comment: FWIW, there's some activity here: https://cgit.kde.org/amarok.git/log/.

Comment: And this is a bit old: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/9bwbgn/what_happened_to_amarok_cannot_find_it_on_pacman/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All applications that do not use the Qt 5 toolkit are being removed from Ubuntu (and Debian).

See https://wiki.debian.org/Qt4Removal (contains a list of qt4 packages and their status in relation to qt5) and specific to Amarok there is a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/amarok/+bug/1757590 about removing it.

Comment: amarok status from Debian wiki: master branch is KF5-based, but no release planned yet